# Do Delvin and Vex's Jobs Hinder Any Further Quests in Windhelm?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am in my second play through Skyrim. I am trying to catch all the things I missed in the first play through.

But this play through I completed [Blood on the Ice](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blood_on_the_Ice) quest first. It was bugged in my last play through.

My one miss was [this](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_%28faction%29#Larceny_Targets) link, I need to finish 125 Delvin and Vex quests to get a safe in the Guild along with the other models on display.

Let me explain, my last play through I was unable to purchase Hjerim (sided with the Imperials + Blood on the Ice quest never triggered.)

I plan on siding with the Imperials again this time also, but after the main quest.

My question is I have been asked to plant evidence by Vex into say Clan Cruel-Sea, or Shatter-Shield for that matter, if I do that, will it break something further down?

Will my choices to help Delvin and Vex plant evidence in Windhelm affect any further quests in Windhelm?

Comment: Short answers: No. The thieves guild use the Radiant system, which is self-contained.

Comment: @Desaiw I had not noticed that safe before!  After reading your post I was able to finish the 125 radiant quests (turns out I was pretty close) and get the safe.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the radiant quests don't affect anything else.

I can not find definitive evidence of this anywhere, but I have done tons of radiant quests for people all around Skyrim and haven't run in to any problems.

I think the basic understanding here is that there are ~infinite radiant quests. And as such, they can not all be intricately connected to all the other story lines.  Each individual radiant quest is just a one-off thing that by itself won't affect the rest of the world.